# Creating a new Quote Total be factored into Tax

Tags: magento

We are creating a new total line item on the quote, such as an oversize charge and this needs to be taken into account when the tax calculation is calculated. We have set it to be before tax, but obviously when looking through the tax total file it doesn't appear to grab other totals or a way to say this total needs to have tax applied.

Has anyone came up with a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can remember all the 'footer' totals (I remember them as being in a `<tfoot>` normally) are based on the subtotal and not each other. If your 'oversize' total block modifies the subtotal after it has been displayed then maybe the tax will calculate the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

In your collect method you can try to add the value to the Subtotal instead of the GradTotal ( $address->setSubtotal ). I'm not sure if it will work or if it will need further adjustments.